# How to write Simple HTTP Echo Service Using SEDA (staged event driven architecture)?

Tags: java, nonblocking, event-driven

In the paper "SEDA: An Architecture for Well-Conditioned, Scalable Internet Services", the SEDA was first published.

SEDA consists of a set of stages, where each stage has a separate thread pool.

Sandstorm is the Java API for SEDA which is available in https://github.com/chenhaodong/seda-sandstorm. Also, Apache MINA uses SEDA inside. Yet these implementations do not have any documentation on how to implement a server using SEDA.

Does anyone know, how to build a very simple echo service using SEDA? (Java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache MINA is the Open source implementation for SEDA.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55727099/apache-mina-how-to-write-a-http-server) has an answer which shows how to build a simple http service using Apache MINA.

Apache MINA is kind of deprecated now (as in 2019), and the technologies used there are very old. Hence I wrote a simple new SEDA lightweight library and an Http Server example, from scratch, as follows.

**SEDA-CORE**

Event.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.handler.EventHandler;

public interface Event {

    public EventHandler getHandler();

}
```

EventHandler.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.queue.Queue;

public interface EventHandler extends Runnable {

    public void onEvent() throws InterruptedException ;

    public void run();

    public void setOutQueue(Queue queue);

    public String getName();

    public void setName(String name);
}
```

Logger.java

```
public class Logger {
    public static void log(String className, String msg){
//        System.out.println("SEDA-CORE LOG ----- "+ className+ "----- \t \t \t"+ msg+" -----");
    }
}
```

Queue.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.event.Event;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.helper.Logger;

import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

public class Queue {

    private int capacity;

    private ArrayBlockingQueue<Event> queue;
    private String name;

    public Queue (int capacity, String name){
        this.setCapacity(capacity);
        this.name = name;
        setQueue(new ArrayBlockingQueue<Event>(capacity));
    }

    public String getName(){return this.name;}

    public void enqueu(Event event) throws InterruptedException{
        Logger.log(this.toString(), "Enqueing attempt for "+event.toString()+" to "+this.toString());
        getQueue().put(event); // if queue is full the calling thread has to wait till this sucess (in our case the main thread or one of event handler threads in the executor pool)
    }

    public Event dequeue() throws InterruptedException{
        Logger.log(this.toString(), "Dequeing attempt "+" from "+this.toString());
        return this.getQueue().take(); // if queue is empty then the calling thread (stage thread) has to wait till the event becomes available
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public ArrayBlockingQueue<Event> getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }

    public void setQueue(ArrayBlockingQueue<Event> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public int getNumElements(){
        return queue.size();
    }
}
```

Stage.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.event.Event;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.thread.pool.ThreadPool;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.handler.EventHandler;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.helper.Logger;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.queue.Queue;

public class Stage extends Thread {

    private Queue inputQueue;
    private Queue outputQueue;


    private int batchSize;

    private ThreadPool threadPool;

    public Stage(Queue inputQueue, Queue outputQueue, int batchSize){
        this.threadPool = new ThreadPool();
        this.batchSize = batchSize;
        this.inputQueue =  inputQueue;
        this.outputQueue = outputQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){

            Event event = null;

            try{
                event = inputQueue.dequeue();
                Logger.log(this.toString(), "Dequeued "+event.toString()+" from "+inputQueue.toString());
            }catch (InterruptedException ex){

            }

            if(event != null) {
                EventHandler handler = event.getHandler();
                handler.setOutQueue(outputQueue);
                handler.setName(this.getName()+"'s Event Handler");
                threadPool.submit(handler);
                Logger.log(this.toString(), "Enqueued " + event.toString() + " to " + outputQueue);
            }else{
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }catch(InterruptedException ex){

                }
            }

        }
    }


}
```

ThreadPool.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.handler.EventHandler;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.helper.Logger;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ThreadPool {

    ExecutorService executorService;

    public ThreadPool (){
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    }

    public void submit(EventHandler handler){
        Logger.log(this.toString(),"Calling submit of "+executorService.toString());
        this.executorService.submit(handler);
    }
}
```

**SEDA-HTTP-SERVER**

BufferEvent.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.event.Event;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.handler.EventHandler;
import handler.BufferEventHandler;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class BufferEvent implements Event {

    private EventHandler handler;
    private ByteBuffer buffer;
    private String requestId;
    private int numRead;

    public BufferEvent(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, String requestId, int numRead){
        this.setBuffer(byteBuffer);
        this.setRequestId(requestId);
        this.setNumRead(numRead);
        this.setHandler(new BufferEventHandler(this));
    }

    public EventHandler getHandler(){
        return this.handler;
    }

    public ByteBuffer getBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }

    public void setBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }

    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    public int getNumRead() {
        return numRead;
    }

    public void setNumRead(int numRead) {
        this.numRead = numRead;
    }

    public void setHandler(EventHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }


}
```

ByteArrayEvent.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.event.Event;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.handler.EventHandler;
import handler.ByteArrayEventHandler;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class ByteArrayEvent implements Event {

    private EventHandler handler;
    private ByteBuffer buffer;
    private String requestId;
    private byte[] data ;
    private int numRead;

    public ByteArrayEvent(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, String requestId, byte[] data, int numRead ){
        this.setBuffer(byteBuffer);
        this.setRequestId(requestId);
        this.setData(data);
        this.setHandler(new ByteArrayEventHandler(this));
        this.numRead = numRead;
    }

    public EventHandler getHandler(){
        return this.handler;
    }


    public ByteBuffer getBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }

    public void setBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }

    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    public void setHandler(EventHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }


    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getNumRead() {
        return numRead;
    }

    public void setNumRead(int numRead) {
        this.numRead = numRead;
    }
}
```

HttpRequestEvent.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.event.Event;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.handler.EventHandler;
import handler.HttpRequestEventHandler;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class HttpRequestEvent implements Event {

    private EventHandler handler;
    private ByteBuffer buffer;
    private String requestId;
    private String request;

    public HttpRequestEvent(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, String requestId, String request){
        this.setBuffer(byteBuffer);
        this.setRequestId(requestId);
        this.setRequest(request);
        this.setHandler(new HttpRequestEventHandler(this));
    }

    public EventHandler getHandler(){
        return this.handler;
    }

    public ByteBuffer getBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }

    public void setBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }

    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    public void setHandler(EventHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public String getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(String request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
}
```

HttpResponseEvent.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.event.Event;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.handler.EventHandler;


public class HttpResponseEvent implements Event {

    private String requestId;

    public HttpResponseEvent(String requestId){
        this.setRequestId(requestId);
    }

    public EventHandler getHandler(){
        return null;
    }


    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }

    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }


}
```

BufferEventHandler.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.handler.EventHandler;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.helper.Logger;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.queue.Queue;
import event.BufferEvent;
import event.ByteArrayEvent;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class BufferEventHandler implements EventHandler {

    private BufferEvent event;
    private Queue outQueue;
    private String name;

    public BufferEventHandler(BufferEvent event){
        this.event = event;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setOutQueue(Queue queue){

        this.outQueue = queue;
    }

    public void  onEvent() throws InterruptedException{

        ByteBuffer buffer = this.event.getBuffer();
        String requestId = this.event.getRequestId();
        int numRead = this.event.getNumRead();


        Logger.log(this.toString(), "Recieved "+event.toString());

        buffer.flip();
        byte[] data = new byte[numRead];
        System.arraycopy(buffer.array(), 0, data, 0, numRead);

        ByteArrayEvent byteEvent = new ByteArrayEvent(buffer, requestId, data, numRead );


        Logger.log(this.toString(), "Set new object to "+byteEvent.toString());

        outQueue.enqueu(byteEvent);

        Logger.log(this.toString(), byteEvent.toString()+" added to "+outQueue.toString());
    }

    public void run(){
        Logger.log(this.toString(), "Running "+ this.toString()+" for "+event.toString());

        try{
            this.onEvent();
        }catch (InterruptedException ex){

        }
    }



}
```

ByteArrayEventHandler.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.handler.EventHandler;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.helper.Logger;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.queue.Queue;
import event.ByteArrayEvent;
import event.HttpRequestEvent;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class ByteArrayEventHandler implements EventHandler {

    private ByteArrayEvent event;
    private Queue outQueue;
    private String name;

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ByteArrayEventHandler(ByteArrayEvent event){
        this.event = event;
    }

    public void  onEvent() throws InterruptedException{

        Logger.log(this.toString(), "Recieved event "+event.toString());

        ByteBuffer buffer = this.event.getBuffer();
        String requestId = this.event.getRequestId();
        byte[] data = this.event.getData();
        int numRead = this.event.getNumRead();

        String request = null;
        try {
            request = new String(data, "US-ASCII");
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex){

        }

        request = request.split("\n")[0].trim();

        HttpRequestEvent httpRequestEvent = new HttpRequestEvent(buffer, requestId, request);

        outQueue.enqueu(httpRequestEvent);

        Logger.log(this.toString(), "Enqueued "+httpRequestEvent.toString() +" to "+outQueue.toString());

    }

    public void setOutQueue(Queue queueu){
        this.outQueue = queueu;
    }


    public void run(){
        Logger.log(this.toString(), "Running "+ this.toString()+" for "+event.toString());

        try{
            this.onEvent();
        }catch (InterruptedException ex){

        }
    }


}
```

HttpRequestHandler.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.handler.EventHandler;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.helper.Logger;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.queue.Queue;
import event.HttpRequestEvent;
import event.HttpResponseEvent;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Dictionary;

public class HttpRequestEventHandler implements EventHandler {

    private HttpRequestEvent event;
    private Queue outQueue;
    private String name;

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public HttpRequestEventHandler(HttpRequestEvent event){
        this.event = event;
    }

    public void setOutQueue(Queue queue){

        this.outQueue = queue;
    }

    private String serverRequest(String request) {
        String response = "";
        if (request.startsWith("GET")) {

        // pass the request and generate response here    

        response = "response";
        return  response;
    }

    public void  onEvent() throws InterruptedException{

        Logger.log(this.toString(),"Recieved "+event.toString());

        ByteBuffer buffer = this.event.getBuffer();
        String requestId = this.event.getRequestId();
        String request = this.event.getRequest();

        Logger.log(this.toString(), "Recieved object inside is "+event);

        String response = serverRequest(request);

        buffer.clear();

        buffer.put(response.getBytes());

        HttpResponseEvent responseEvent= new HttpResponseEvent(requestId);

        Logger.log(this.toString(), "Set new object inside "+event.toString());

        outQueue.enqueu(responseEvent);

        Logger.log(this.toString(), responseEvent.toString()+" added to "+outQueue.toString());
    }

    public void run(){
        Logger.log(this.toString(), "Running "+ this.toString()+" for "+event.toString());

        try{
            this.onEvent();
        }catch (InterruptedException ex){

        }
    }


}
```

QueueMonitor.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.helper.Logger;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.queue.Queue;

public class QueueMonitor extends Thread {
    private Queue[] queues;

    public QueueMonitor(Queue[] queues){
        this.queues= queues;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(9000);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){

            }

            for(Queue queue: queues){
                Logger.log(this.toString(), queue.getName()+" is "+queue.getNumElements());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ThreadMonitor.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.helper.Logger;

public class ThreadMonitor extends Thread{

    private Thread [] threads;

    public ThreadMonitor(Thread [] threads){
        this.threads= threads;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(11000);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){

            }

            for(Thread thread: threads){
                Logger.log(this.toString(), thread.getName()+" is "+thread.getState());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

HttpEventMain.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.queue.Queue;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.stage.Stage;
import event.BufferEvent;
import monitor.QueueMonitor;
import monitor.ThreadMonitor;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class HttpEventMain extends Thread
{
    private InetAddress addr;
    private int port;
    private Selector selector;
    private ConcurrentHashMap concurrentHashMapResponse;
    private ConcurrentHashMap concurrentHashMapKey;

    public HttpEventMain(InetAddress addr, int port) throws IOException {
        this.setAddr(addr);
        this.setPort(port);
        this.setConcurrentHashMapResponse(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
        this.concurrentHashMapKey = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("----- Running the server on machine with "+Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()+" cores -----");


        try {
            System.out.println("\n====================Server Details====================");
            System.out.println("Server Machine: "+ InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName());
            System.out.println("Port number: " + this.getPort());

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            this.startServer();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error occured in runnable.HttpEventMain:" + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        HttpEventMain server = new HttpEventMain(null, 4333);
        server.start();


    }
    private void startServer() throws IOException {
        this.selector = Selector.open();
        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);


        InetSocketAddress listenAddr = new InetSocketAddress(this.addr, this.port);
        serverChannel.socket().bind(listenAddr);
        serverChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        System.out.println("Server ready. Ctrl-C to stop.");

        Queue inQueue = new Queue(100, "In Queue");


        Queue outQueue1 = new Queue(100, "Out Queue 1");
        Queue outQueue2 = new Queue(100, "Out Queue 2");
        Queue outQueue3 = new Queue(100, "Out Queue 3");

        int batchSize = 10;

//        Stage stage = new Stage(inQueue, outQueue, batchSize);

        this.setName("Event Main");

        Stage bufferstage = new Stage(inQueue, outQueue1, batchSize);
        bufferstage.setName("bufferstage");
        Stage byteArrayStage = new Stage(outQueue1, outQueue2, batchSize);
        byteArrayStage.setName("byteArrayStage");
        Stage httpRequestStage = new Stage(outQueue2, outQueue3, batchSize);
        httpRequestStage.setName("httpRequestStage");

        ResponseMannager responseMannager = new ResponseMannager(concurrentHashMapResponse, outQueue3);
        responseMannager.setName("responseMannager");

        Thread [] threads = {this, bufferstage, byteArrayStage, httpRequestStage, responseMannager};

        ThreadMonitor monitor = new ThreadMonitor(threads);

        monitor.start();

        Queue [] queues = {inQueue, outQueue1, outQueue2, outQueue3};

        QueueMonitor queueMonitor = new QueueMonitor(queues);

        queueMonitor.start();


        bufferstage.start();
        byteArrayStage.start();
        httpRequestStage.start();

        responseMannager.start();


        while (true) {

            this.selector.select();

            Iterator keys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keys.next();

                keys.remove();

                if (! key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    this.accept(key);
                }
                else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    this.read(key, inQueue);
                }
                else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    this.write(key);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void accept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {

        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
        SocketChannel channel = serverChannel.accept();
        channel.configureBlocking(false);


        Socket socket = channel.socket();
        SocketAddress remoteAddr = socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();

        channel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }

    private void read(SelectionKey key, Queue inQueue) throws IOException {

        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
        int numRead = -1;
        try {
            numRead = channel.read(buffer);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (numRead == -1) {

            Socket socket = channel.socket();
            SocketAddress remoteAddr = socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
            channel.close();
            key.cancel();
            return;

        }

        String requestID = RandomStringUtils.random(32, true, true);
        while(concurrentHashMapKey.containsValue(requestID) || concurrentHashMapResponse.containsKey(requestID)){
            requestID = RandomStringUtils.random(15, true, true);
        }
        concurrentHashMapKey.put(key, requestID);
        try {
            inQueue.enqueu(new BufferEvent(buffer, requestID, numRead));
        }catch (InterruptedException ex){

        }

        concurrentHashMapResponse.put(requestID, false);

        channel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE, buffer);
    }

    private boolean responseReady(SelectionKey key){

        String requestId = concurrentHashMapKey.get(key).toString();
        Boolean response = (Boolean) concurrentHashMapResponse.get(requestId);

        if(response==true){
            concurrentHashMapKey.remove(key);
            concurrentHashMapResponse.remove(requestId);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    private void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {

        if(responseReady(key)) {
            SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = (ByteBuffer) key.attachment();
            inputBuffer.flip();
            channel.write(inputBuffer);
            channel.close();
            key.cancel();
        }else{
        }

    }


    public ConcurrentHashMap getConcurrentHashMapResponse() {
        return concurrentHashMapResponse;
    }

    public void setConcurrentHashMapResponse(ConcurrentHashMap concurrentHashMapResponse) {
        this.concurrentHashMapResponse = concurrentHashMapResponse;
    }

    public InetAddress getAddr() {
        return addr;
    }

    public void setAddr(InetAddress addr) {
        this.addr = addr;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public Selector getSelector() {
        return selector;
    }

    public void setSelector(Selector selector) {
        this.selector = selector;
    }
}
```

ResponseMannager.java

```
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.helper.Logger;
import com.pasindu.queue.seda.queue.Queue;
import event.HttpResponseEvent;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class ResponseMannager extends Thread{

    ConcurrentHashMap concurrentHashMapResponse;
    Queue inQueue;

    public ResponseMannager(ConcurrentHashMap concurrentHashMap, Queue queue){
        this.concurrentHashMapResponse = concurrentHashMap;
        this.inQueue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true){
            HttpResponseEvent event = null;
            try {
                event = (HttpResponseEvent) inQueue.dequeue();
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){

            }

            if(event!=null) {

                Logger.log(this.toString(), "Dequeued " + event.toString() + " from " + inQueue.toString());
                concurrentHashMapResponse.put(event.getRequestId(), true);
                Logger.log(this.toString(), "Set response availabliity for " + event.getRequestId() + " in " + concurrentHashMapResponse.toString());
            }else{
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }catch(InterruptedException ex){

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```